# How to provide a "create page" link to a specific namespace?

Tags: mediawiki

For most "normal" people it's not easy to understand what this whole "namespace thing" in MediaWiki is. I want to provide a link to them to create a page in a specific namespace without the need to worry they understand what's going on.

Some like:

> If you want to create a page for your project, click here: **MySpecialNamespace-Create-Link**

There should then be a page they can fill in the page name and it's automatically in the right namespace. Is this easily possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `<inputbox>` to achieve that. See [extension description page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aInputBox) on MediaWiki.

Here is an example. Clicking the 'create page' button takes you to `Namespace:DefaultPageName`. See it in action [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aBencmq/sandbox).

```
<inputbox>
type=create
default=DefaultPageName
prefix=Namespace:
buttonlabel=create page
bgcolor=#f0f0ff
width=50
break=no
</inputbox>
```

There are a few more parameters you can play around with to make it better. The documentation on MediaWiki is very straightforward.